# Execute a subquery in MySQL that returns multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I am executing a query that obviously contains a subquery in MySQL.

Let me just jump into the code:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), 
(SELECT due FROM checkOut JOIN People ON checkOut.p_id = People.p_id
 WHERE CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(date_add(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 4 MONTH), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
 >= checkOut.checkTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY checkOut.due)
 );
```

The main query is the `SELECT DATEDIFF()`. Within that is my subquery which essentially searches through the table to look for items that are overdue based on an interval. I know that there will be multiple rows returned from the query and that it will not work with how I currently have it set up.

What I want are multiple values to be returned from my `SELECT DATEDIFF()`, so that I can loop through it with php later. To elaborate, I want each of the rows returned in the subquery to have an associated value from `DATEDIFF()`. How can I modify this query to do what I want? Or if anyone has a better method, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated.

In case you are wondering the why there is a `DATE_ADD()` within the `DATE_SUB()`, it is to simply make the query work for today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get rid of the subquery, you can calculate the difference directly.

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due), due 
FROM    checkOut JOIN People 
            ON checkOut.p_id = People.p_id
WHERE   CASE 
           WHEN DATE_SUB(date_add(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 4 MONTH), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
                    >= checkOut.checkTime 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
        END 
ORDER BY checkOut.due
```

Comment: That's interesting. Out of curiosity, is there a performance difference between using subqueries or not? It works great by the way.

Comment: That's what I was looking for (y)

Answer (score 0):

Use the subquery as table. e.g. below:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), d.due)
FROM 
 (SELECT due FROM checkOut JOIN People ON checkOut.p_id = People.p_id
  WHERE CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(date_add(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 4 MONTH), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
       >= checkOut.checkTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY checkOut.due) 
  ) AS d;
```